# Image Positioning using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the size of the image as well place the image `background-position:center 10px;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
<head><title>TFZIM3 RDA</title></head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<body style="background-color:d8d8d8;" >
    <img class="normal" src="main.png" width="700" height="80" />

</body>
```

css

```
img.normal
{
background-position:center 10px;
}
```

but this is not working.

Please guide

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious... I have a couple thoughts that might help but I need a little more information first. 1) Does the image need to be an image, or would it be acceptable to display it as the background? 2) Also, do you have to have the site as xml? or can it be html5? 3) how important is browser support? CSS3 can help but does not play well with all browsers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resize an image you'll have to use a server-side language such as php. You cannot do it with a markup language.

As for centering an image, the `background-image` property is used for backgrounds, not for images. Images are inline elements. Therefore a `text-align: center;` to parent block element should work. However, If you want to place an image and make it fullscreen I'd use this code:

```
<head>
    <style>
    body { position: relative; z-index: 0; }         

    .bg { 
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -100;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="bg" src="path/to/your-image.jpg">
</body>
```

[Check the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fBWZv/)

**Edit**

To make a full-screen background image, I now use the CSS3 `background-cover` property. You may use it like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- head code -->
        <style>
            body { 
                background: url('path/to/img') no-repeat center fixed;
                webkit-background-size: cover;
                  -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                       background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- body code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

According to [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) site, the compatibility is pretty much good.

Answer (score 0):

You are styling the image, ie giving the image a background image. Try something like the following:

```
body {
    background:url(main.png);
    background-size:700px 80px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center 10px;
}
```

Then you can also lose the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ggJa/1/) (**updated**)

Image is resized using `background-size: 100% 100%` the values in `%` describe what percentage of the parent should image take.

**[+`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-size)**  **[+`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-position)**